# ハンバーガーメニューをページ内リンクの時に閉じるには

Tags: javascript, jquery

フルスクリーンハンバーガーメニューで、
ページ内リンクの場合にメニューを閉じるにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

```js
$('#toggle').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
   $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');})
```

```css
.button_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
}

.button_container.close {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
}

.button_container:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.button_container.active .top {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translateY(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
  background: #fff;
}
.button_container.active .middle {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.button_container.active .bottom {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
  background: #fff;
}
.button_container span {
  background: #fe5d86;
  border: none;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button_container span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 11px;
}
.button_container span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 22px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: #fe5d86;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, visibility 0.35s, height 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, visibility 0.35s, height 0.35s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay.close {
  position: fixed;
  background: #fe5d86;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, visibility 0.35s, height 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, visibility 0.35s, height 0.35s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay.open {
  opacity: 0.9;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}
.overlay.open li {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInRight 0.5s ease forwards;
          animation: fadeInRight 0.5s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.35s;
          animation-delay: 0.35s;
}
.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
          animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.45s;
          animation-delay: 0.45s;
}
.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
          animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.overlay nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "Noway-round";
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}
.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  height: calc(100% / 5);
  min-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay ul li a:hover:after, .overlay ul li a:focus:after, .overlay ul li a:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}
.overlay ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: 0.35s;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button_container" id="toggle">
  <span class="top"></span>
  <span class="middle"></span>
  <span class="bottom"></span>
</div>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="_index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="_index.html#prof">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="_index.html#lesson">Lesson</a></li>
      <li><a href="_index.html#info">Information</a></li>
      <li><a href="_index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $('#toggle').click(function()

で、付けたり外したしているclass（'active'と'open'）をメニューのリンクがクリックされたら、
削除（removeClass）すれば良いです。